Masterpiece theater movie with Damien Lewis and Jaime Murray
I'm trying to find the name of a movie, which is similiar in genre to the British masterpiece theatre movies (1920s or earlier).
If memory serves, it stars Damien Lewis as a rich person who pushes Jaime Murray to marry him.  She says that she'll marry him if he never asks for love.  He agrees.  His brother, on the other hand, who I do not remember the actor, has horrible bad luck all the way to the end of the movie.
Throughout the movie Damien Lewis keeps asking for her for a child, and she keeps reminding him of the agreement.  He starts to get upset, and through the movie starts to put increasing pressure on her for love and children.  His advances increasingly continues, and she starts asking for divorce.  He refuses because in his mind, she should be giving children.  
In the last act of the movie, she and the brother hides in a home, (her from her husband, and him from the pains of life) to which they talk and start to kiss.  Damien Lewis catches them, calls her a bunch of bad names, and then says he is going to divorce her.
In the last scene, she gives birth to a child to the brother, to which he is still sour on.  However, in a while, a blonde (which was nowhere in the movie) says she'll marry him and gives him a daughter.
If you guys can help me figure out the name of this movie, I'd be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Curious, have you looked at their IMDb pages? Also, when did you see this show/when do you think it came out?

The obvious answer, which may be wrong, is the 2002 version of The Forsyte Saga, which was presented on PBS as part of Masterpiece Theater. The woman who plays Damian Lewis's wife does look similar to Jamie Murray but it is actually Gina McKee.
It is based on a series of novels of the same name by John Galsworthy set in early 1900s England.
Here's the trailer:




That was it.  You are right.  That's why I couldn't find it on IMDB.  I was looking for Jamie Murray.  They really did look identical.  Thanks.
